# What is this unknown 7214 while running JPS on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

What is this 7214 when I run the `jps` command.

```
17134 SecondaryNameNode
16934 NameNode
**7214** 
17401 Jps
17249 ResourceManager
17024 DataNode
17365 NodeManager
```

Comment: Could it be something else that is running on your JVM? Does it always appear when you start hadoop? Does it appear before you start hadoop?